# Reorder row values from lowest to highest

Tags: python, pandas

I'm attempting to take a dataset with 5 columns of data and order the data in each row from lowest to highest. So far I've come up with a method that will loop through 0-4 and return value, but I get stuck at there as I can't figure out how create columns for all 5 row values. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('ValueOrder.csv')

df_2 = pd.DataFrame()

for val in [0,1,2,3,4]:

    df_2 = df_2.assign(val=df.apply(lambda x: np.partition(x, val)[val], axis='columns'))

print(df_2)
```

Data:

```
S1       S2      S3      S4      S5
1629027 1627752 203145  1713    203458
1629027 45222   1627752 203145  1713
1629027 203458  203145  1627752 1713
1627752 203145  203458  45222   1629027
1627752 203145  1629027 1713    45222
```

Expected outcome:

```
 S1      S2      S3      S4      S5
1713    203145  203458  1627752 1629027
1713    45222   203145  1627752 1629027
1713    203145  203458  1627752 1629027
45222   203145  203458  1627752 1629027
1713    45222   203145  1627752 1629027
```

Comment: @roganjosh probably still a dupe, but that sorts by an explicit row.  This doesn't maintain column order.

Comment: Ooops, not a dupe of that

Comment: @user3483203 saw it exactly at the time you posted :)

Comment: @roganjosh I want to say yes but that only argsorts the entire thing by one of the rows. They want each row to be sorted individually. This is a job for `np.sort(... axis=1)` but I can't find that dupe.

Comment: More precisely, the answer is `df[:] = np.sort(df, axis=1)` but I cannot find a dupe.

Comment: Found a dupe but with a different axis, still think it applies.  EDIT, found the right one

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.values, axis=1), index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
```

Output:

```
      S1      S2      S3       S4       S5
0   1713  203145  203458  1627752  1629027
1   1713   45222  203145  1627752  1629027
2   1713  203145  203458  1627752  1629027
3  45222  203145  203458  1627752  1629027
4   1713   45222  203145  1627752  1629027
```