# Create new columns from existing column and sort the values from smallest to largest

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to locate all values greater than 0 within columns n_1 to n_3 inclusive, and populate them into columns **new_1**  to **new_3**  inclusive in order of smallest to largest, such that column **new_1** has the smallest value and **new_3** has the largest value. If any columns are not populated because there are not enough values to do so, then populate them with 0

```
EVENT_ID    n_1      n_2    n_3
            
143419013   0.00    7.80    12.83
143419017   1.72    20.16   16.08
143419021   3.03    12.00   17.14
143419025   2.63    0.00    2.51
143419028   2.38    22.00   2.96
143419030   0.00    40.00   0.00
```

Expected Output:

```
EVENT_ID    n_1      n_2    n_3    new_1  new_2   new_3             
143419013   0.00    7.80    12.83  7.80    12.83  0.00
143419017   1.72    20.16   16.08  1.72   16.08   20.16 
143419021   3.03    12.00   17.14  3.03   12.00   17.14
143419025   2.63    0.00    2.51   2.51   13.78   0.00
143419028   2.38    22.00   2.96   2.38   2.96    22.00 
143419030   3.92    40.00   11.23  40.00  0.00    0.00
```

I tried using the **apply** function to create this new column but I got an error down the line.

```
df[['new_1','new_2','new_3']] = pivot_df.apply(lambda a,b,c: a.n_1, b.n_2, c.n_3 axis=1)
```

Comment: What do you mean "If any columns are not populated because there are not enough values to do so, then populate them with 0" Can you provide an example of this case? Because it currently seems like [standard sorting across rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54207772/15497888): `df[['new_1', 'new_2', 'new_3']] = np.sort(df[['n_1', 'n_2', 'n_3']], axis=1)`

Comment: @HenryEcker Thanks for the response. What I meant by that is for columns where the values are **NA** we can populate those values by 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's subset the DataFrame remove values that do not meet the condition with [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html), then use [`np.sort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) to sort across rows and [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) to replace any missing values with 0:

```
cols = ['n_1', 'n_2', 'n_3']
df[[f'new_{i}' for i in range(1, len(cols) + 1)]] = pd.DataFrame(
    np.sort(df[cols].where(df[cols] > 0), axis=1)
).fillna(0)
```

`df`:

```
    EVENT_ID   n_1    n_2    n_3  new_1  new_2  new_3
0  143419013  0.00   7.80  12.83   7.80  12.83   0.00
1  143419017  1.72  20.16  16.08   1.72  16.08  20.16
2  143419021  3.03  12.00  17.14   3.03  12.00  17.14
3  143419025  2.63   0.00   2.51   2.51   2.63   0.00
4  143419028  2.38  22.00   2.96   2.38   2.96  22.00
5  143419030  0.00  40.00   0.00  40.00   0.00   0.00
```

---

Setup used:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'EVENT_ID': [143419013, 143419017, 143419021, 143419025, 143419028,
                 143419030],
    'n_1': [0.0, 1.72, 3.03, 2.63, 2.38, 0.0],
    'n_2': [7.8, 20.16, 12.0, 0.0, 22.0, 40.0],
    'n_3': [12.83, 16.08, 17.14, 2.51, 2.96, 0.0]
})
```

`df`:

```
    EVENT_ID   n_1    n_2    n_3
0  143419013  0.00   7.80  12.83
1  143419017  1.72  20.16  16.08
2  143419021  3.03  12.00  17.14
3  143419025  2.63   0.00   2.51
4  143419028  2.38  22.00   2.96
5  143419030  0.00  40.00   0.00
```

Comment: the new columns have **0** values at the beginning of it. I value > 0 at the beginning of it and we are done populating the column with the real values, we can then fill in 0 for the values towards the end.

Comment: When you have additional requirements, it's important to demonstrate that with your example. You have additional conditions on how you want to handle missing values, however, you don't show that in your question. I believe you're saying that you'd like to sort the NaNs to the end then fill the zeros afterwards. We can do that by fillna after sort instead of before. Please see the edits.

Comment: the mistake was from my end, I already updated the question with the correct input and output. I want to locate all values greater than **0** in the old column and use that to populate the newly created column. If any columns are not populated because there are not enough values to do so, we populate them with zero. I just updated the input and output in the original question

Comment: @ChukypedroOkolie just confirmed the current code produces the expected output using the updated input data.

Comment: Thanks for taking out to help me on this. I really appreciate it. I have accepted your solution